# It's possible to control how automatic generated labels of <f:selectItems> are displayed?

Tags: css, jsf

I have a dynamic list of options who is displayed in a `<h:selectOneRadio>`, and I want to control the labels layout so when the label are greater than one line it behaves like this :

Actual behavior:

```
    [ ] Label 1

    [ ] This label really 
    bugs me!

    [ ] Label 3
```

Desired behavior:

```
    [ ] Label 1

        Now...This is a nice     
    [ ] Label, Label, label, 
        Label, Label, label ...

    [ ] Label 3
```

Simplified HTML generated by JSF:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="radio 1" type="radio"> 
                <label for="radio 1"> Label 1 </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="radio 2" type="radio"> 
                <label for="radio 2"> This Label really bugs me! </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="radio 3" type="radio"> 
                <label for="radio 3"> Label 3 </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

UPDATE: Sorry =X, I needed something slightly different...

Comment: In future questions to CSS experts, it'd be more helpful if you post the JSF-generated HTML output along in the question as CSS experts usually have no idea what HTML code the mentioned server side component is generating (in this case it's just an ordinary HTML `<table>` with each radio button `<input>` and `<label>` in the same `<td>`)

Comment: You didn't clearly describe the functional requirement, but based on the ASCII art, I understand that you want both the input and label vertically centered in the table cell and that the label text shouldn't wrap around the input element, is this understanding complete and correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I have the same layout as above with checkboxes,  which i can control manually with <h:panelGrid>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using `layout="pageDirection"` to lay the list vertically and you can have the list in fixed width, you can do something like this:

<sub>**Disclaimer:** Tested only in FF and Chrome</sub>

```
<style>
.select-one {
   width: 200px;
}
.select-one label {
   float: right;
   width: 170px;
}
</style>
...
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBacking.ola}" layout="pageDirection"
     styleClass="select-one">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="This label really bugs me" itemValue="one" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="This label really, really, REALLY bugs me!!
                                 And let's add more stuff into this"
                      itemValue="two" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

This is how it renders in Firefox:

[image: Rendering in Firefox Nightly]

You may have to twidde with the values for the CSS `width` definitions a little bit, to make it to your taste.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I haven't tested, because I needed something slightly different.. See my updated question..

Comment: @Bacaneiro Well, please test it out then, cause I still think I had it right the first time. See the added screenshot.

Comment: Thank you again, I'm trying to adapt your solution to my problem. I think I just need a position:absolute and some math with the height to correctly align the label :) . I'll let you know if i got any results..

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I tried putting `position:relative; top: 40%;` on the `input` element, but it doesn't work very well for the different heights. Seems that it's hard to get a fairly good vertical alignment across browsers...